# Recurrence Relation For Linear Search Using Recursion

Tags: java, algorithm, recursion, time-complexity, linear-search

What would be the recurrence relation for the following code and how to solve them ?

```
public class LinearSearchUsingRecursion
{
    public static int linearSearch(int array[], int i, int n, int k)
    {
        if(i == n)
        {
            return -1;
        }
        
        if(array[i] == k)
        {
            return i;
        }
        
        i = i + 1;
        
        return linearSearch(array, i, n, k);        
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        
        int array[] = {5,8,7,9,6,0};
        int n = array.length;
        
        int k = 9;
        
        int pos = linearSearch(array, 0, n, k);
        System.out.println("Position : " + pos);

    }

}
```

I have tried and I am getting as:-

```
T(n) = T(i+1) + 1
T(1) = 1
```

Is it correct ?
How we can represent i in terms of n and solve it ?

Answer (score 0):

It should be

`T(n) = T(n-1) + 1`

`T(1) = 1`

The time should be a function of the size of the input i.e. `n` and not index of the array.

You take first element do a constant work i.e. compare it to `k` and then you proceed with the remaining size `n-1`.

If you have only one element, it is `T(1) = 1` only one comparison.

Comment: Yes, it seems to be okay in general case. But here, I provided the program and based on that approach we have to form the recurrence relation. It is obvious from the program that in every recursive call i is incremented. So, considering that we have to form relation by converting i to n.

Comment: Recurrence relation doesn't depend on implementation detail. It doesn't matter whether you implement it recursively or iteratively.

Comment: I think, recurrence relation is totally dependent on the code. Given a piece of code, we have to construct our recurrence relation based on the code. Let us say the above code is not of linear search, then from which line u can say that we are working on remaining n-1 elements on every recursive call. Do I am decrementing n in every recursive call..

Comment: What I meant is recurrence relation depends on the algorithm not the implementation.

Comment: I don't think so. In order to solve a problem there can be a algorithm that can be implemented using different data structures. Different implementations can give different recurrence relations and hence different time complexities.